# When typedef is used in C, will it create a new type or only a type name?

Tags: c, types, typedef

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Books {
     char title[50];
     char author[50];
     char subject[100];
     int book_id;
} Book;

int main( ) {

  Book book;

  strcpy( book.title, "C Programming");
  strcpy( book.author, "Nuha Ali"); 
  strcpy( book.subject, "C Programming Tutorial");
  book.book_id = 6495407;

  printf( "Book title : %s\n", book.title);
  printf( "Book author : %s\n", book.author);
  printf( "Book subject : %s\n", book.subject);
  printf( "Book book_id : %d\n", book.book_id);

  return 0;
}
```

> Here in this example, Book is a new Data type or its just an alternate name to structure?

or in other words if the code is :`typedef unsigned char newDType;`
`newDType` is a new data type or alternate name to `unsigned char`?

Comment: Just curious.. what difference does it make to you (or anyone)?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: It can make a great deal of difference. For example, if `typedef int my_int;` created a distinct type, then `int*` and `my_int*` would be incompatible, and you could not assign one to the other without a cast. Instead, they are the same type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`typedef` specifier **msdn** page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05w82thz.aspx) (*click to know more*)

> A `typedef` declaration introduces a name that, within its scope, becomes a synonym for the type given by the type-declaration portion of the declaration.

---

So, as quoted **the new name is just an alternative name**(*synonym*) for the original type. Generally, `typedef` declarations are used to make declarations more uniform and compact.

Answer (score 8):

The definitive answer to this is in the ISO C standard. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) is the latest draft. Section 6.7.8 paragraph 3 says:

> A **`typedef`** declaration does not introduce a new type, only a
>   synonym for the type so specified.

Similar wording appears in all previous editions of the C standard, and going back at least to the first edition of Kernighan and Ritchie (K&R1), published in 1978.

Answer (score 4):

No, `typedef` creates an alias for a type and using either effectively becomes  equivalent.

Quoting [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef):

> The `typedef` declaration provides a way to declare an identifier as a type alias, to be used to replace a possibly complex type name
>   [...]
>   `typedef` declaration does not introduce a distinct type, it only establishes a synonym for an existing type

And it is *essential* that to happen, because otherwise opaque types -heavily used in interfaces- would not be possible.

Comment: I dont understand your last sentence, and how it follows from the rest of the argument.

Comment: @Vality: Consider `FILE`, which is a `typedef` for an internal `struct` you don't and shouldn't see. [Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/68336110?noredirect=1) it's important to match other declarations. If it created a different type, this wouldn't be possible. Does that help?

Comment: Ah, yes that does make some sense. I see what you mean now. (You might even put that into your answer as it is an exceptionally good example). +1

Answer (score 3):

If we are talking comparative programming languages, typedef does not create a new type. It effectively creates an alias for a type.

Answer (score 0):

In relevant header file:

```
typedef struct Vec3f{
    float x, y, z;
}Vec3f;
```

In relevant .c file:

```
Vec3f myVector;
myVector.x = 27.5f;
myVector.y = 2.0f;
myVector.z = 1.2f;


Vec3f my;
my.x = 7.5f;
my.y = 23.0f;
my.z = 12.2f;

SDL_Log("%f, %f, %f\n", myVector.x, myVector.y, myVector.z);
SDL_Log("%f, %f, %f\n", my.x, my.y, my.z);
SDL_Log("%f, %f, %f\n", myVector.x, myVector.y, myVector.z);
```

Prints as expected.